# Docker needs to be an object not '<class 'NoneType'>'

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

i'm new in `Docker` and i'm trying to use docker with `Laravel`. i installed docker on `ubuntu` and this output is installation version of that:

```
Docker version 18.09.1, build 4c52b90
```

i created `docker-compose.yml` in project root and below is content of the file

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - "3306:3307"
    environment: 
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'homestead'
      MYSQL_USER: 'homestead'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'secret'
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
  app:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    image: 'Tcms'
    ports: 
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
```

now when i try to run this command:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

i get this error:

```
ERROR: Top level object in './docker-compose.yml' needs to be an object not '<class 'NoneType'>'.
```

i'm not sure intended lines are correct, however i check that and i think that's correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see people getting this error when they forget to save `docker-compose.yml` file so it is empty when you run it...have you?

Even so, I suggest that you [upgrade Docker's version](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#upgrade-docker-engine) so you can have better error messages.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that seems out of place for me is image: 'Tcms'

Since you are defining a dockerfile, the dockerfile should be the one to define the image name.  Remove that line and you should be good to go.

Comment: Defining `image:` and `build:` together [is well-defined](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build): it specifies the image name when you `docker-compose build`, instead of letting Compose generate one.  (The Dockerfile can't specify the image name at all.)